# Apache server isn't working though changing port number

Tags: apache, xampp

I have changed my apache server port number to 81 . But i am unable to start my apache server of xampp in my windows7 32 bit. I have also tried it with port 1724.But can't find any good result.

Comment: How did you change the port number ?

Comment: And what does "unable to start" mean?

Comment: Hi @ligherror how You solved the problem?